# Semantic ui/npm problems/gulp installation

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

ok so while did some semantic installation each time when i try something i get errors

npm install -g gulp

```
   npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back  gulp@3.9.0 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/gulp'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/gulp'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-22-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/kristjan
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kristjan/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

then with rooted user i get this

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
/usr/local/bin/gulp -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
gulp@3.9.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp
├── interpret@0.6.6
├── pretty-hrtime@1.0.1
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── semver@4.3.6
├── tildify@1.1.2 (os-homedir@1.0.1)
├── v8flags@2.0.11 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.1.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.4, supports-color@2.0.0, ansi-styles@2.1.0, strip-ansi@3.0.0, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.1.5)
├── liftoff@2.2.0 (extend@2.0.1, rechoir@0.6.2, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.1.6, findup-sync@0.3.0)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.14 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, mkdirp@0.5.1, strip-bom@1.0.0, defaults@1.0.3, vinyl@0.4.6, through2@0.6.5, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6)
└── gulp-util@3.0.7 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-uniq@1.0.2, beeper@1.1.0, fancy-log@1.1.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._reevaluate@3.0.0, lodash._reinterpolate@3.0.0, object-assign@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, has-gulplog@0.1.0, vinyl@0.5.3, gulplog@1.0.0, lodash.template@3.6.2, multipipe@0.1.2, through2@2.0.0, dateformat@1.0.12)
```

so what im asking can you guide m througt how to get semantic on my pc? it annyed the hell out of me..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to run gulp as root. Here's how you can install semantic UI:

1. Download Semantic UI as zip from [Github](https://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/)
2. cd to the `Semantic-UI-master` folder where you have `dist/` and `src/` folders
3. Run `npm install` - this will install gulp and all other dependencies listed in the `package.json` file.
4. You will be asked with steps to continue which are self-explanatory. All the compiled CSS and JS will go inside `dist/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

works for me by installation previous version 2.16, then update to latest version.

npm install semantic-ui@2.1.6 --save-dev
cd semantic/
gulp build
npm update //

answer coming from https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000004267891